QT undefined reference to external lib function

I'm new to c++ and currently trying to create QT login-register GUI app with hashing passwords. For Bcrypt I'm using this library
So, I copied it, created binaries with CMake GUI and than builded them with VS2019. Then added following code into QT .pro file:
LIBS += -L"S:/work/proga/includes/Bcrypt.cpp/build/Release/" -lbcrypt
INCLUDEPATH += S:/work/proga/includes/Bcrypt.cpp/include

and some basic code in main.cpp (include and usage of lib)
But faced errors like this:
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `bcrypt::generateHash(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'

So. How I should fix it?
upd, my .pro file:

QT       += core gui sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

SOURCES += \
main.cpp \
loginwindow.cpp \
profileinfo.cpp \
registerwindow.cpp \\

HEADERS += \
User.h \
loginwindow.h \
profileinfo.h \
registerwindow.h \\

FORMS += \
loginwindow.ui \
profileinfo.ui \
registerwindow.ui

LIBS += -L"S:/work/proga/includes/Bcrypt.cpp/build/Release/" -lbcrypt
INCLUDEPATH += S:/work/proga/includes/Bcrypt.cpp/include

main.cpp like
#include <iostream>
#include <bcrypt.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::string password = "top_secret";

    std::string hash = bcrypt::generateHash(password);

    std::cout << "Hash: " << hash << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\"" << password << "\" : " << bcrypt::validatePassword(password,hash) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\"wrong\" : " << bcrypt::validatePassword("wrong",hash) << std::endl;
}

<3
Tried to use another bcrypt lib (this), but also faced undefined reference errors. Maybe I'm dumb (yes), but can't understand what I should do now..
Tryed to read about this such of error, but didn't find any solution for me (I'm dumb)

Does this answer your question? Adding external library into Qt Creator project

Looks like you provided the library path, but forgot to ask the linker to link with your bcrypt.

I tried to add -lbcrypt after LIBS += -L"...", but that didn't work

Oki, is it also reproducible if you don't use https://github.com/trusch/libbcrypt/tree/master directly? It has BCrypt::generateHash(password); so this additional C++ wrapper from https://github.com/hilch/Bcrypt.cpp seems redundant.

Yes.
I tried to use another lib, maybe it will work (no).

Could be that on windows the linker options are not generated correctly. I can reproduce it with CMake and MinGW: cmake --build . fails, but invoking compiler explicitly c++.exe -L"LIBDIR" -I"INCLDIR" main.cpp -lbcrypt works fine. Try to invoke your VS2019 cl.exe directly from command line and see if it links correctly.

I apologize, but I don't really understand what to do. I can launch cl.exe from the terminal using call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" and Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt will be launched.

Also, I don't quite understand about linking the library using ./login register -L "myLibPath" -I "myIncludePath" main.cpp -lbcrypt, it displays error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++-6.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. But I can't build a project with errors (either in QT or in VS), so I commented out the part of the code where functions from the lbcrypt library are called.

Most likely, I just misunderstood you because I am generally not very familiar with more in-depth topics of c++ than Olympiad programming

You would need to wait for someone who can help with VS2019. I don't have access to it right now and I hate microsoft in general. In the meantime you can try to make your question a bit more minimal (e.g. remove *.cpp and *.h that are not necessary to reproduce the problem). Or switch to linux (on windows you can use WSL2 to install Ubuntu22), and your project will compile and work out of the box.
